# How can I define a heteregeneous list datatype?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am just starting to learn SML and having issues. I want to define a datatype, for a list that is not homogeneous.
Take for example

```
val a = [1,[2,4,3],5,[2,6]]
```

I have made this datatype

```
datatype 'a MulList = List of 'a multiList list
                    | E of 'a;
```

but I get the following error

```
/tmp/emacs-region29207RwC:8.34-8.43 Error: unbound type constructor: multiList

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: datatype 'a MulList= List of 'a multiList list
                    | E of 'a;

I create this but I think it may have better syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datatype declarations has a few errors. First off it is good practice (as you do) to capitalise the first letter of the value constructors, however it is also good practice to have a type constructor in all lower case.
The real error you have is that you reference your `mullist` type as `multiList` when you define the value constructor `List`.

With that fixed, you can create your multilist:

```
datatype 'a mullist = List of 'a mullist list
                    | E of 'a

val a = [E 1, List [E 2, E 4, E 3], E 5, List [E 2, E 6]]
```

Comment: thank u for your answer, you're right. but I just copy it wrong,srry. you mean this is only delcration for mullist? is that good? Is there any other nice syntax?

Comment: It is not necessarily the only way of making a "multilist", however it would all depend on the situation. However I would say that this is a suitable solution for the presented problem.

Comment: so what should I do if I want to swap the elements with this format `E 1` for example?

Comment: @sarahysh, could you be more specific? I don't have a clue what you are talking about.

Comment: I have nested list as I said ([1,[2,4,3],5,[2,6]]) I want to swap 2 element of it. so define this data type (mullist),now with this type I can't swap and I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: The list `[1,[2,4,3],5,[2,6]]` cannot exist, as its type is not valid. That is why you created the multilist type. The multilist `[E 1, List [E 2, E 4, E 3], E 5, List [E 2, E 6]]` is however valid. 

You wan't to swap two elements in such a multilist? So the result might be `[List [E 2, E 4, E 3], E 1, E 5, List [E 2, E 6]]` if we swapped the two first elements?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I think I should make some changes on multilist `[List [E 2, E 4, E 3], E 1, E 5, List [E 2, E 6]] `that I can have `[[2,4,3],1,5,[2,6]]`. but how? i don't know. I'm not sure.

Comment: It is simply not possible to declare a value of `[[2,4,3],1,5,[2,6]]`.  The type system doesn't allow for such a type. It is the same reason that you can't have this list `[1, "1.1", 1.1]`. SML is a statically typed language, meaning the type system needs to know all types at compile time. It is not possible to know what type the n'th element has, at compile time (when n is unknown).

Comment: you'r right. anyway thank u for your help, it's helpful. Meanwhile this is the question: www.cs.toronto.edu/~afsaneh/csc324w13/a1.pdf (Question1.a)