# How can I convert my data type?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I define a data type for a multi list:

`datatype intnest= INT of int 
                | LIST of intnest list;`

now I'm trying to write function which can convert this type to main type.

for example: 

`[INT 1, INT 2, LIST[INT 6, INT 8]] => [1,2, [6,8]]`

how can I do this?
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787639/how-can-i-define-a-heteregeneous-list-datatype), specifically what we discussed in the comments.

Comment: yes but I define a function that convert this, but just convert type INT to int I can't handle other type `LIST`.

Comment: actually I just want to show in manual way in output, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787639/how-can-i-define-a-heteregeneous-list-datatype), you can't!

As i tried to explain: It is not possible to have such a value in SML!

Just try it out in your interpreter

```
- val _ = [1,2, [6,8]];
stdIn:28.9-28.21 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: int * int list
  operand:         int * int list list
  in expression:
    2 :: (6 :: 8 :: nil) :: nil
```

If we construct the list with the basic constructs instead of the syntactic sugar, then the list `[1,2,3]` becomes `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: nil`

Now, if we look at the types of the two "building blocks" cons and nil

```
- op::;
val it = fn : 'a * 'a list -> 'a list
- nil;
val it = [] : 'a list
```

then we see that the infix operator cons, takes an argument of type `'a` on the left hand side and a list of `'a` on the right hand side.
Thus we can see that if we build a list of ints, then we must give it an int on the left hand side and a list of ints on the right hand side (as the example above).  It should be clear from this that we can't to anything like this:

```
[1, 2] :: 3 :: nil
```

which is equivalent with `(1 :: 2 :: nil) :: 3 :: nil`

Comment: ` datatype intnest = INT of int | LIST of intnest list;
 fun tagged2s (INT i) = valOf(Int.fromString (Int.toString i))         map tagged2s [INT 1,INT 4]; `

Comment: it results: `val it = [1,4] : int list` but I don't khow how can I do this work for type list. I hope to understand my meaning.